# Confused on why I am getting a Cross-Origin Request Blocked error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dns, cross-domain

I know that there are several posts about this topic, but I am a little confused as to why I am getting "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://ipaddress/json. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS." There is a Rest API that I am trying to access that is currently on a device with IP Address xyz. This Rest API is a CGI script that I had developed in C.

Right now, my device where I am running this code is also connected to the same Wifi, with IP Address xyz. So wouldn't that mean that the resource is not remote as it is under the same domain?

This is my JavaScript code in case anyone is curious.

```
<button id="submit" onclick="fun()">Click here!</button>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function fun()
{
  $.getJSON('http://ipaddress/json', function(data) 
{
    alert(data.toSource());
    console.log(data);
});
}
</script>
```

I am not necessarily asking for a solution to this issue, as I know that there are many online, but I'm more curious as to why I am getting this problem and where I was wrong with my understanding of this error. I also tried experimenting with a couple other public JSON sites:

Using `https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos` did not result in this error and returned the correct information.

However, using `https://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json` did result in this error. I'm assuming this could be because GitHub added CROS to their server?

Any understanding would be appreciated.

Comment: you can trivially verify it yourself. use something like httpfox in firefox to view the requests from your browser to the specified site, and see what the `OPTIONS` request reply looks like (if any) when you try the ajax call.

Comment: When the CORS specification says "same domain", it means that the entire name after `//` must be the same as the origin. Being on the same network, or having the same domain suffix aren't good enough. `foo.domain.com` and `bar.domain.com` are not the same domain, neither are `192.168.2.10` and `192.168.2.20`.

Comment: If you have a cable modem, your public IP and your neighbor's IP are likely the same except for the last couple of digits. Would you really consider them to be in the same domain just because they use the same cable company?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be same origin, a URL must have the same protocol (e.g. "http"), same port and same domain.  If you're using direct IP address in the URL instead of domain, it must have the same IP address.

It does not matter that you are on the same WiFi or the same local network.  All that matters is the origin in the URL of the web page that the Javascript is running in as compared to the origin of the URL you are making the Ajax call to.

If you are the same origin, requests will work without CORS enabled on the server.

If you are not the same origin, the server will have to enable CORS before the browser will let the Ajax call be made.

If you see specific cross origin ajax calls that work, then those destination servers must have enabled CORS.

---

**Bottom line:** If you are trying to access your own CGI script with an ajax call and you are using an IP address in the URL and the web page that the Ajax call is being made from did not also come from that same IP address, then you need to add CORS support to your CGI script so that the browser will allow the request to be made.

Or, move your CGI to the same IP address that the web page comes from.

Comment: Alright, that makes more sense then. Yeah, the two ip addresses do differ so I will proceed to add CORS to my CGI script. Is adding just CORS to my CGI Script enough, or do I also need to add CORS support to the web server I am using (NGINX). Also, not sure if you would know the answer to this question, but is adding CORS support to the CGI script in C as easy as `printf("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`? Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @trynacode - You don't need CORS support on the server that the web page comes from, only on the server that the Ajax call is being made to.  There may be a bit more involved than what you suggest for CORS support (it depends on your ajax call).  There are thousands of articles on the topic so you should be able to find the right guidance with Google.  Depending upon your particular Ajax call, you may also need to implement support for the OPTIONS command, in addition to the GET because the browser may precede the GET with an OPTIONS - depending upon the particular Ajax call.